# How to remove annoying error message popping up for an add-on that is no longer installed?

Tags: error, boxcutter, log

I completely removed the addon 'BoxCutter' as I simply do not need it in my arsenal. However, whenever I switch to "Layout" tab in order to work with rigging and such - I keep getting an error message and it's getting on my nerves because this addon no longer exists, I removed it.

Tool 'Boxcutter' not found for space 'VIEW_3D'

It's like a slap in the face "Yeah you removed me but hahahaha still here!" It's getting on my nerves.

I even saved a new startup file, with boxcutter removed, yet it still acts like it's there.

How can I stop this annoying little.. Shi..... Rascal... From popping up? I don't even know what the "VIEW_3D" is as I never even use the damn thing. I just want to work but this thing is like a damn hyperactive chihuahua pinging up and down in my peripheral vision and it's driving me nuts!

Is there a way to at least disable the error messages?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you remove it "completely"? Deleted the files from your drive where they were saved? Have you disabled it in the _Preferences_? Or did you click on _Remove_ in the _Preferences_?

Comment: I removed it in my addons under preferences.

Comment: I googled and found some old bug reports where this error is mentioned for other tools than boxcutter. It seems that there was some tool selected and the startup file was saved to have this tool selected on startup. Now that the tool is no longer there, it throws an error. After opening Blender, can you open up the tool menu in the viewport with `T` and select one, then save a new startup with this tool selected and try again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment yet, so sadly this is my best guess answer as I haven't reproduced your error.

Attempt Gordon Brinkmann's commented solution first.

Otherwise navigate to the addon directory of your blender installation and wipe out anything Boxcutter related.

On Windows it'd under:
`C:\%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\`
On Linux it'd be under:
`~/.config/blender/3.6/scripts/addons/`

Replace 3.6 with your blender version and see if there's anything there that Blender could attempting to load in that relates to the Boxcutter addon.